# Появления окна действия рядом с нажатым объектом

Tags: css3, css, javascript

Приветствую.

Есть необходимость появления окна действия рядом с нажатым объектом! - сделал, работает!

В моем случае (тестово) это квадратик рядом с телефоном. рис 1
[image]

Когда нажимаем на него появляется окно и элементы нише смещаются. рис 2
[image]

Код HTML:

```
<div id="smssendlid">
<div class="top"><span class="heading-gray" style="font-size:18px !important;margin-left:3px;">Отправить sms</span><div class="icons-item close-item close"></div></div>
<div class="content">
<div class="sms">
<textarea name="sms_text" id="sms_text"></textarea>
<input type="hidden" name="id_lids" id="id_lids" value="<? echo $orders_value['id']; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="id_staff" id="id_staff" value="<? echo $userdata['id_staff']; ?>">
<div style="float:left;width: 175px;padding-top:10px;">
                                            <input class="buttonm button-blue" type="submit" name="submit" id="sub_sms_submit" value="Отправить SMS">
</div>

</div>
</div>
<div id="sub_satus_sms"></div>
</div>
```

Код js:

```
$('.sms-send-lid').bind('click', function () {

// Получаем ID блока, который нужно показать
var title = $(this).data("target");

// Показываем блок
                                    $(this).after($(title));
                                    $(title).slideDown(500);
});

// При уходе мышки со ссылки
$('.close').bind('click', function () {

// Получаем ID блока, который нужно показать
// Скрываем блок
                                    $('#smssendlid').slideUp(500);

});
```

Код CSS:

```
#smssendlid {display:none;top:-184px; left:38px !important;height:170px; width:350px; background:#fff;position:relative;left:10px; z-index:1010;    box-shadow:0 0 8px rgba(15,15,15,.25);border: 1px solid #ccc;color:#000;font-weight:100;font-size:13px;line-height:17px;text-shadow:none;border-radius: 3px; -moz-border-radius:  3px; -webkit-border-radius:  3px;}


#smssendlid:before {top: 98%;left: 90%;border: solid transparent;content: " ";width: 19px;height:19px;position: absolute;background:url("img/arrow_doun.png") no-repeat;}
#smssendlid .top {width:322px;  padding: 8px 14px; margin: 0;  font-size: 14px;  font-weight: normal;  line-height: 18px;  background-color: #f7f7f7;  border-bottom: 1px solid #ebebeb;  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;}
#smssendlid .top  span {}
#smssendlid .top .close {float: right;right: 4px;top: 2px;position: absolute;}
#smssendlid #timeout {width:170px;margin-top:10px;}
#smssendlid .button-blue {margin-top:10px;margin-left:2px;width:170px !important;}
#smssendlid .content {text-align:center;font: 14px/16px "Ubuntu Condensed", Arial, "Helvetica CY", "Nimbus Sans L", sans-serif;}
#smssendlid .content .disc {margin-top:10px;margin-bottom:20px;height:30px;color:#151515;}  

#smssendlid .content textarea { width: 300px;  height:40px;}
#smssendlid .content #sub_sms_submit {float: left;}
#smssendlid .sms-success, #smssendlid .sms-error {width: 300px;margin:20px auto;text-align:center;font: 26px/34px "Ubuntu Condensed", Arial, "Helvetica CY", "Nimbus Sans L", sans-serif;}
#smssendlid .sms-success .success-img {background:url("img/success.send.png") no-repeat; background-size:100%; width: 60px; height:60px;margin:5px auto;}
#smssendlid .sms-error .error-img {background:url("img/success.send.png") no-repeat; background-size:100%; width: 60px; height:60px;margin:5px auto;}
```

Comment: а где вопрос ?

Comment: сделайте position absolute

Comment: hb абсолютном позиционировании показывает где-то вверху вообще вне нужной области...

Comment: значит для блока где квадрат задайте position: relative; а для самого всплывающего окна position: absolute;

Comment: да-да, так и сделал, проблема решилась